How far back can we derive reasonably accurate survival function estimation from historical records?
Actuarial science is the profession of modeling and managing risk. Modern actuary started some point between the 18th to 19th century to address the need of pension planning. It estimates the longevity of an individual (or the risk of death) so the contribution to a pension fund can be calculated. Early attempts to mathematically characterize the risk of death in the form of the life table can be traced as early as 1662.
However, people have been keeping historical records way longer than compiling life tables. In popular media, there are also frequent talks of life expectancy of medieval peasant. Based on both the archival and physical records existed today, how far back can we derive reasonably accurate survival function estimation?
Survival function is a tool to model the risk of death. When referring to a human, it gives the probability of an individual will survive past a certain time.
Bruce R. Troen in The Biology of Aging (1) has an estimation on Europe 15000 years ago and Africa 50000 years ago from evolutionary point of view.
Biehler-Gomez et. al estimated the survival function of a Roman Milan population (2).
Clark estimated the survival function of a post-medieval Dublin population (3).
Yaussy and DeWitte estimated the survival function of a medieval London population (4).

Welcome to History SE! Please edit with evidence of previous research. Without a clear definition of what allows "reasonably accurate survival function estimation", I'm not sure if there's an answerable question here or not.

Coming from a biology background, it is easy to draw a survival curve. Bruce R. Troen in The Biology of Aging has an estimation on Europe 15000 years ago and Africa 50000 years ago. Hence the limit on reasonable accuracy. I will update it if I can find a better working definition in the literature.

Can you define survival function for those of us who don't know?

@MCW: From context and the definition given (namely "it gives the probability [that] an individual will survive past a certain time"), it appears to be the function that is integrated (possibly with additional weighting/scaling factors) to obtain life expectancy. So perhaps  L.E. = ∫ t⋅(s(t)⋅dt  with s(t) the survival function at age t

@PieterGeerkens Thanks for the additional information. Yes, the integral of the survival function is life expectancy. A brief definition of survival function was added in the last edit.

It should be noted that we can estimate the survival function by using a sample of ages at death and an estimate of rate of grow of population. That is, we don't need accurate records but just a cemetery. Of course, the more data, the better estimate, but the estimates you mention aren't intended to be as exact as the ones given every year by modern census offices.

Parish records go quite a ways back, and people moved around less 300 years ago or more.

I think Chinese records might be the way to go - the Qin Dynasty was obsessed with bureaucracy, so I wouldn't be surprised to find that they have age-related records.
